# Using LIKE wildcard with % operator in SQL xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, wildcard, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to use the % operator in the xp_cmdshell like below.

```
DECLARE @OutputFilePath nvarchar(max);
SET @OutputFilePath = '\\shared data\Everyone Share\';
DECLARE @ExportSQL nvarchar(max);
SET @ExportSQL = N'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell
  ''bcp "SELECT FileID, NAME FROM [Process].[dbo].[Vendor] WHERE FileName LIKE ''%'' + AAMG + ''%''" queryout "' + @OutputFilePath + '\OutputData.csv" -T -c -t -S WIN-db02''
' 

EXEC(@ExportSQL)
```

But it is throwing me an error saying **Incorrect syntax near '%'**

If i just remove the LIKE part, the entire code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you tried *debugging* your statement by selecting or printing it?

Comment: Honestly, why use TSQL to execute `bcp.exe` it's not a generalized scripting language? just use batch file or Powershell eg `bcp "SELECT FileID, NAME FROM dbo.Vendor WHERE FileName LIKE '%' + AAMG + '%'" queryout ($OutputFilePath + '\OutputData.csv') -T -c -t -S WIN-db02 -d -d "Process"`

Comment: perhaps try to wrap the LIKE clause with parentheses `LIKE ('%AAMG%')` but i'm not sure about executing this from the shell

Comment: The percent character has special meaning to the windows command shell, and that may be triggering the error. Try doubling up the %s to escape them. The command shell should then replace them with single %s when it executes the final bcp select statement.

Comment: Double up the single quote around the `%` => `LIKE ''''%'''' + AAMG + ''''%''''" queryout`

Comment: What's the point of such code? Why weaken security to use `xp_cmdshell` instead of just executing `bcp` directly? Or use SSIS? If you want to run exports on a schedule, SQL Server Agent already allows running shell commands

Comment: As already mentioned, the very first step in debugging this is to print out the string you are executing and take a look at it. Don't just blat a bunch of code and scratch your head when it doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried this and this prints perfectly as expected in print.
`SET @sql` = 'SELECT FileID,Name FROM [Process].[dbo].[Vendor] WHERE FileName LIKE ''%AAMG%'''
`print @SQL`

but if  i paste the same inside bcp, it says incorrect syntax near '%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(reproduce here from comments. it is easier to read here)

You need to double up the single quote around the `%`

```
SET @ExportSQL = N'
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell
  ''bcp "SELECT FileID, NAME FROM [Process].[dbo].[Vendor] WHERE FileName LIKE ''''%'''' + AAMG + ''''%''''" queryout "' + @OutputFilePath + '\OutputData.csv" -T -c -t -S WIN-db02''
'
```

Looks like AAMG is a constant string and not a column name. In this case, change the dynamic query to

```
LIKE ''''%AAMG%''''"
```

Comment: says invalid column name 'AAMG'

Comment: is that a constant string or a column name ?

Comment: If that is a constant string, you don't need to do concatenation  `% + AAMG + %`, should simply use `LIKE '%AAMG%'`

Comment: yes, its a constant string, ''''%AAMG%''''" worked like a charm